what is the way to find out if a selected token will revert at 0 transfer
How can I find out if the selected token will revert to 0 transfer? Is there a list of tokens that revert at 0 transfer. As far as I understand USDC is one of them, is that correct ? Thanks in advance!

You can simulate a transaction using eth_call for example.
With ethers v5 (docs), it's something like this:
await tokenContract.callStatic.transfer(from, to, 0);

You can simply check if it raises any errors or not.
